# Different capacity batteries in parallel?

Tags: battery-charging, battery-operated

I have two [VRLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VRLA_battery) batteries, 2Ah and 7.2Ah in capacity. Both are 12v. What would happen if I connect them in parallel when they are charged to the same voltage?  can I use them to power a 10w LED?  what will be the effect on the two batteries in parallel when drawing current from them? (These are to be used with a 10W solar panel)

Comment: Everyone is going to say no. Don't do it. And you probably shouldn't. But it has a good chance of working OK, at least for a while. I think something bad might happen when the batteries start to go bad. You could end up in a situation where all the charge current goes into the small battery and causes it to overheat. You wouldn't know unless you were monitoring temperature. So I advise you not to do it, too.

Comment: Since batteries with different size/type/capacity have different internal resistance, there will be an imbalance in terms of discharge and performance when they are connected in parallel. This will result in discharging one of them faster and make it even overheat.

Comment: Will work just fine. Just be careful when initially making the first connection between the batteries. Miniscule differences in SoC (voltage) can cause excessive current to flow from one battery to the other until they balance out. You may want to temporarily put a load *between* the batteries to limit that current. After a while, the batteries will have the same voltage and will charge and discharge in parallel just fine.

Comment: Huh?  What's a "VRLA" battery?  I'm guessing LA stands for Lead Acid, but that still leaves VR.  This is a international list, so abbreviations should not be used unless they are *very* common or universal.  "Ah" is OK, for example.

Comment: "Valve regulated lead acid"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting batteries in parallel (concerns)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131830/connecting-batteries-in-parallel-concerns)

Answer (score 2):

i'm not an expert but...

"Most [battery chemistries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/serial_and_parallel_battery_configurations) lend themselves to series and parallel connection. It is important to use the same battery type with equal voltage and capacity (Ah) and never to mix different makes and sizes. A weaker cell would cause an imbalance. This is especially critical in a series configuration because a battery is only as strong as the weakest link in the chain...

A weak cell may not fail immediately but will get exhausted more quickly than the strong ones when on a load. On charge, the low cell fills up before the strong ones because there is less to fill and it remains in over-charge longer than the others. On discharge, the weak cell empties first and gets hammered by the stronger"

you need only 1ah to run a 10watt load on a [12v battery](https://www.batteryweb.com/pdf/inverter_battery_sizing_faq.pdf). your 2ah will last 2 hours from a full charge if you use only that. if you need it to run longer then the 7.2AH would last most of the night.

Comment: It's just fine to put different batteries (capacity) in parallel providing they are the same technology (all lead acid all LiPo all NiCad etc), You don't need balancing electronics and cannot overcharge a smaller capacity one in parallel with a larger capacity one. Because they are connected together the terminal voltages track intimately and the batteries self balance.  When being discharged the same intimate terminal matching ensure you cannot disproportionally discharge one battery. Many of the laptop batteries you see contain both series and parallel strings of cells.

Comment: @JackCreasey, and I heard just opposite. Each battery cell has slightly different parameters due to manufacturing variabilities, even in the same batch, due assembly variations, etc. The only reason the parallel sections in laptops work (and this is a questionable assertion, there are zillions of partially dead laptop batteries around) is because battery manufacturers carefully characterize and bin production batches, and only well-matched cells (impedance, charge-discharge profile, terminal voltage) make it into parallel sections.

Comment: @Ali Chen.  Providing the batteries are the same type (chemistry) their charge and discharge characteristics will be similar enough to have no problems. You can read more here: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/serial_and_parallel_battery_configurations        ......the only real concern occurs in LiPo batteries where a cell that shorts would become a heat sink for current from adjacent cells. Even then it is very customary to see serial string connected in parallel. The RC environment (who use 3+ C discharge rates have been doing this for years for both NiCad and LiPo.

Comment: @JackCreasey, could you put some quantification on what is "similar enough" and what constitutes "no problem". If two battery cells (in parallel) have different shape of discharge function, and, say, left in a laptop at 60% charged, will it constitute somewhat faster self-discharge than carefully matched cells? The layman article does not address this concern.

Comment: @Ali Chen. Since the terminals are tied together there can be no potential difference between the cells  Any difference in discharge or charge curves can only appear as differences in output/input resistance. In good cells these values will be milli Ohms and since the terminals are tied they result only in a current imbalance. Consider a worst case with a bad battery with 10 times the R of the other, it delivers less current at any given Vterm but does not influence the other battery in any way. it delivers only the current it can at this Vterm.

Comment: @JackCreasey, I asked for any engineering quantification. Please read this, http://www.mpoweruk.com/balancing.htm  ***No matter what battery management techniques are used, the failure rate or cycle life of a multicell battery will always be worse than the quoted failure rate or cycle life of the single cells used to make up the battery.***

Comment: So it's safe to just connect two batteries (same voltage, same chemistry) in parallel and treat as if it was a single battery?

Comment: @IshanFdo1 I think its safe to say at the level of output you are using in this question it is not going to burn your house down if you do. It is simply bad practise and mostly unnecessary when you can Just use either battery depending on how much you are going to be lighting the Led.  lol, Lighting the Led... there should be a song.

Comment: But depth of discharge affects in battery lifetime a lot. So connecting them on parallel will allow me to reduce the depth of discharge on each battery

Comment: @Ali Chen. Great link, which points out all the problems associated with series connection of cells. It does correctly point out the more cells you have the higher the risk of seeing a failure (simply because of cell count). It then goes on to say you can build using lots of parallel hybrid cells, the problem only coming when you series connect those larger cells.

Comment: If the batteries use their own protection circuit and charge circuit it will operate fine. The only downside is that the lower capacity turn off first when battery gets drained.

Comment: Putting batteries of the same chemistry in parallel is virtually the same as using larger electrode area inside one single battery. Because two different areas of a battery's electrodes are nothing but in parallel. And just as there will be some harmless inhomogeneities across the electrode area of one single battery, there may be harmless inhomogeneties between different cells put in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you say charging batteries to the same voltage, as you can see in the picture below, a lot of batteries have a pretty consistent voltage output even though the state of charge is definitely decreasing, because of this voltage is usually a really bad way to compare charge.

[image]

Better way is to charge and deplete batteries, measure the actual energy going out and determining it in such a way. Also the changes in batch, build and all will definitely cause one of the batteries to charge/discharge more quickly then the other even if they were identical battery models.

From your question I understand you want to use the batteries as energy buffer/storage for your solar panels and power a LED of those, The easiest solution would be to just use 7.2Ah battery by itself.

Comment: When they are in parallel that's not a problem, right?

Comment: If the two VRLA batteries are completely identical apart from the  Ah rating, it will be perfectly fine. As long as the relationship between voltage and charge state is the same for both batteries it  works.

I just prefer safe then sorry, and with the age, deterioration and everything unknown. I dont really see the added value of the few Ah eventhough it will most likely work.