# If cells in series are mismatched in capacity, will the capacity tend to even out?

Tags: batteries

A [closed question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/271005/different-capacity-batteries-in-parallel) is about cells in *parallel*, and does have hints about series, but it also has contradictory answers and comments.

We have more than a dozen alkaline AA cells, and the only current test method (without going out and buying another device) is to put them in a TV/satellite remote and look foe a "change batteries" message on the TV screen.

But the remote takes four, and if we get that message, it's possible one or more of the cells is still good.  They're cheap, so it would be reasonable to just dump all the unknowns in a recycling bin and buy more, but **if we keep using them until we see the message, are all of them pretty much empty?**

Comment: The capacity will be the capacity of the smallest or weakest cell.

Comment: As an answer to a question, this should be in an answer, not a comment.  On the other hand, it doesn’t really answer my question, which is in bold.

Comment: I'd argue the @BrianDrummond comment as a comment **does** answer your question.

Comment: the comment definitely answers the question .... perhaps @BrianDrummond should have worded it `no, the capacity will be the ...`

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have cells with different capacity in series, the lower capacity ones will discharge faster. If you put a AAA and a AA in series and lit up an LED, after a while the AAA would be at a significantly lower voltage than the AA.

AA cells are *relatively* well matched in capacity and output impedance, but there certainly can be differences based on the manufacturer. Some of the cheap ones use different chemistry and have lower capacity (zinc), so if you mix them with higher capacity cells (alkaline) in series, they will discharge unevenly.

If the cells in your remote are made by different manufacturers, or are in different stages of discharge/use, you may end up in a situation where some of the cells are 'dead' (have a prohibitively high series resistance) and some can still be used. Unless you put all the cells in the device 'brand new', you don't have a legitimate basis to assume they're all dead once you see the message.

Why don't you pick up a cheap multimeter and see for yourself? You don't need anything crazy, a $10 multimeter would do.

Comment: I was speaking of nominally-the-same cells that (presumably) have not had the same amount of use.

Comment: In that situation, the used cell will start at a lower voltage and will stay lower than the remaining cells for the duration of use. They won't just balance themselves. Rechargeable batteries in series sometimes do have active balancing, however.

Comment: This mostly answers the question, though it might be nice to edit in that comment, along with the implied question, should I expect the message to appear when all are depleted, or just when the lowest one is depleted?

Comment: Edited to explicitly answer your question

Comment: I do have what seemed a pretty good meter when I bought it.  I should be able to judge, as I taught electronics for a few years and was a tech (not an engineer) for longer.  But it isn’t working now, and the cells in it came from the collection in question.